# Eliminar un opcion de un select al hacer click en el select

Tags: jquery

Tengo una serie de combos de tipo `<select>` donde se tienen que mostrar tres valores y que se estan mostrando bien.
La funcionalidad que necesito es que al recibir el foco, es decir que se haga click o que tabulando se llege a el y se despliege, se elimine uno de los valores pero unicamente para ese combo,en concreto el que tiene por valor vacio `option[value='']`

Estoy intentando hacerlo creando una clase llamada `.eliminarblanco` que tienen todos los combos pero no consigo seleccionar dentro de la función el elemento en concreto que hace click, el que llega por el evento, para que lo elimine

```
     $(".eliminarblanco").on('focus', function (event) {
        //Aqui es donde no veo como hacer para que en pseudocodigo fuese algo como $((this).option[value='']").remove();
    });
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías utilizar la función `.find()` para buscar la opción a eliminar y después eliminarla, algo talque asi:

```
$(".eliminarblanco").on('focus', function (event) {
        $(this).find("option[value='']").remove();
});
```

**Ejemplo**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="cars" class="eliminarblanco">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="">Audi</option>
          </select>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(".eliminarblanco").on('focus', function (event) {
            $(this).find("option[value='']").remove();
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Un modo sencillo de hacerlo es con ocultando con `hide` la opción según su valor. Para que sea en el `select` en el que haces `click`, recoges la `id` en el evento `click` y gestionas las opciones para esa `id`.
Ejemplo:

```js
$(".myselect").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#'+id+' option[value=""]').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1" class="myselect">
  <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
  <option value="">Opción a borrar</option>
  <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
</select>
<select id="select2" class="myselect">
  <option value="">Opción a borrar</option>
  <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
</select>
```